# CAN bus communication via BeagleboneBlack and Simulink

Tags: simulink, beagleboneblack, can-bus

I have a running Simulink model communicating with a CAN bus. Messages are received, postprocessed and sent again. Now, I want to see this code running on a BeagleBone Black (BBB).

What is the simplest way to put a Simulink model with CAN Receive/Transmit blocks on the BeagleBone Black?

Do I need a CAN cape? What is the benefit of a CAN cape?

Is there a simple toolbox so that I do not need to write my own code on the BBB?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Simulink support automatic code generation that you can download your simulink model to BBB. https://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/beaglebone-black.html

Comment: Thank you for your help.
However, I still have to connect my CAN to the BBB, but don't know how to configure Simulink accordingly so that I can receive and send the messages.

Comment: You certainly need a CAN transceiver to connect your BBB to the real CAN network. You can use either CAN cape or make your own CAN interface circuit and connect it to BBB, it's up to you. When you'll do this you'll need to configure BBB GPIOs with CAN functionality to operate "in CAN mode", for that you need to write/download and add a device overlay. When you'll finish that you can try to simply listen some messages on the bus to verify that on the hardware side you are ok. After that you can go and add your simulink soft and all other crazy stuff you like.